GMocking function call with side condition
I expect function "bar" of class "foo" to be called when variable "a" equals 42.
The following code-under-test should result in an unsaturated expectation/failed test:
int a = 41;
foo.bar();

The following code-under-test should result in a successful test:
int a = 41;
a++;
foo.bar();

How can this be done with Googlemock? I thought about the following approach but couldn't find a fitting matcher.
EXPECT_CALL(mock,foo).With(someMatcher)


Does this answer your question? Mocking free function

I reformulated the question: my problem was not about a free C function, the problem was about the global variable "a" that needs to be checked somehow.

I would make it like this
#include <gmock/gmock.h>

#include <iostream>

class foo : public ::testing::Mock {
 public:
  MOCK_METHOD(void, bar, ());
};

int a = 41;

TEST(Test, Case) {
  foo mock;
  EXPECT_CALL(mock, bar()).WillOnce([] {
    if (a != 42) FAIL();
  });

  a++;
  mock.bar();
}

https://godbolt.org/z/edKKo738n

I like the compactness of using a lambda function, however, even though it works it seems a bit counter-intuitive. The expectation is initially met but then forced to fail within the action. Could you think of a way to not satisfy the EXPECT_CALL in the first place (e.g. with a matcher - or otherwise)?
